# How to set one selected logo on existing image using Canvas and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need some help. I am setting some text on image using canvas but this time my requirement is I have to set one logo on that image using Canvas/ Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```
<img class="img-responsive thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:9px; display:none;" src="images/coupon-banner-blank.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" id="requiredImage">
<canvas id="canvas" name="canvas" class="img-responsive thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:9px;"></canvas>
<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo">

<script>
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  img = document.getElementById('requiredImage'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  img.onload = drawImage;
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.font = "24px Calibri";
  var y=10;
  var cnt=0;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText('A special Offer from AT&T', 160, 70);
  ctx.fillText('20% OFF', 190, 110);
  ctx.fillText('Your entire purchase', 190, 150);
  ctx.fillText('drawing', 60, 280);
  var dataURL=document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL();
</script>
```

Here is my output image

[image]

Here I can set the text on the image but here my requirement is I need to set one logo by selecting from input file field on this image somewhere in left middle position. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Can you show the current output

Comment: Click the `<>` snippet editor and add an image from lorem pixel

Comment: @Kuru : I have updated my post please check it. I need to set any logo that `acer` place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish that in the following way ...

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    img = document.getElementById('requiredImage'),
    logo = document.getElementById('logo'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var y = 10;
var cnt = 0;

function drawImage() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.font = "24px Calibri";
    ctx.fillText('hello', 160, 70);
    ctx.fillText('hii', 190, 110);
    ctx.fillText('copun', 190, 150);
    ctx.fillText('drawing', 60, 280);
}

// upload local image
logo.onchange = function (e) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); //set position as you wish
    };
};

var dataURL = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL();
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<img class="img-responsive thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:9px; display:none" onload="drawImage()" src="http://i.imgur.com/Q6aZlme.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" id="requiredImage">
<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo">
<canvas id="canvas" name="canvas" class="img-responsive thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:9px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: No output is coming .Please check.

Comment: But I couldnt see any image after upload.

Comment: definitely your answer is too appropriate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144327/discussion-between-subhra-and-nd).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. Make sure the position of the logo won't change.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("logo");
     var bg = document.getElementById("bg");
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 10, 10,220,227);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10,100,100);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="bg" src="http://www.seobook.com/images/smallfish.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">
<img id="logo" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/655066410087940096/QSUlrrlm.png" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>


<p><strong>Note:</strong> The canvas tag is not supported in Internet 
Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Simply you need to change position of second draw image. For more [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp).

Comment: Let me to test and let you know.

Comment: Then you can give me a green tick :)